# how to set up virtual environment for jee/spring development

Tags: jakarta-ee, docker, vagrant, virtual-machine, development-environment

I want to begin a new jee/spring project and I want to change the way I work.
Usually I just set up my tomcat on Windows and launch intellijIdea to start. What I want to do now is to set up a virtual machine based on linux system (Debian will be great) and have a tomcat server installed so that i can access from my host computer throught url : VirtualMachineIP:TomcatPort/MyProject.

I heard that docker and vagrant are good references to get this done, but i really want a cookbook recipe or a good link for an article that explain step by step how to set all this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to make an answer even though you have chances that you question will get closed as 'primarily opinion'

both docker and vagrant could do the job for you - using one or the other is matter of preference, but lets say

- if you deploy on production on container : go for docker
- if you're alone in your team and only uses it for development : go for docker
- if you want to reflect a production infrastructure : go for vagrant

If you go for docker, the most simple will be to start with [a tomcat docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/tomcat/), you have almost all flavor of Java/Tomcat version so you should be good to go

If you go for vagrant, its not as simple as first you need to select an OS (on which you will run) and then provision the installation of the software (should be OS agnostic when using chef/puppet/ansible tools) so it gives you more freedom to select your tool, but with freedom comes choice.

so first select the OS you want to run a select a [valid box](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/boxes.html) then select which [provisioning tool](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/) will make the install, can be that straight shell instructions is sufficient for you, else look for available puppet/chef/ansible module/recipie/playbook is available to build your stack. check also [google](https://www.google.fr/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=vagrant+box+tomcat) as others have probably done the same.

So it might not be as easy for vagrant to get a link that described all as each article will deal with a different tool.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer CentOS in this case, it's more popular as a server, just install java and tomcat in the vm (in virtualBox: settings-network-port forward) make the forwarding of ports from localhost of vm to your localhost...for this see the screenshot: [image]. P.s guest IP must be 10.0.2.15.link to install tomcat: https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-install-tomcat-on-centos/

Comment: Thanks. This solution is good, but i don't want each time to install my Os manually in virtual box that's why i want to use vagrant or docker.